# Sort a collection of randomly generated numbers

Tags: c#, random

I am creating a random number generator in c#

I generate the numbers as so

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();

Num1.text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
Num2.text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
Num3.text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
Num4.text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
Num5.text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
Num6.text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
```

The user clicks a button and the numbers are generated, what I want is for there to be a button which can sort the numbers, so for example smallest to lowest.

Could I turn the numbers generated into an array and call .ToArray and then sort from there? I am unsure how to group the random numbers together to then call a sorting method on them.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: why can't you store all the numbers in array by adding them every time you instantiating a new number and then just sort...

Comment: it's easier to sort on a List<T> personally Stanislav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the random numbers to a list and sort them.

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
List<int> list = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    list.Add(RandomClass.Next(1, 49));
list.Sort();

// If you need to reverse it...
list.Reverse();
```

If you are comparing to a `List<string>` you will need to write a comparer.

Example:

```
private static int CompareValues(string x, string y)
{
    if (x == null)
        return y == null ? 0 : -1;
    else
    {
        if (y == null)
           return 1;
        else
        {
           int left = Int32.Parse(x);
           int right = Int32.Parse(y);

           if (left > right)
               return 1;
           else if (left < right)
               return -1;
           else
               return 0;
        }
     }
 }
```

Then to use it, pass it as argument to the `Sort()` method. This will now be used as a custom compare to handle the integer values and sort them properly.

```
 list.Sort(CompareValues);
```

Comment: I want to apply this code to the 'sort' button in my code. I have copy and pasted this into the button but nothing happens when pressed. Is this because I am re calling a new instance of random?

Comment: What are you applying sort to, what type of Collection. It depends on the type, due to the variation of the comparer of the respective type.

Comment: To strings, once I get a random number i use the .ToString. What I want to do is once the user clicks on the sort button after generating the numbers for them to be sorted. Should I store them in a list inside the generate method and then call the list.sort() inside the sort method?

Answer (score 0):

If you store the random numbers in a list, you could sort (or manipulate them in a number of ways) easily using Linq. Assuming your method returns random integers:

```
var myRandomNumbers = new List<int>
    {
        RandomClass.Next(1,49),
        RandomClass.Next(1,49)
    };

var mySortedRandomNumbers = myRandomNumbers.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

Of course, if you're *always* calling `RandomClass.Next(1,49)` you could optimize with a loop and use `.Add()` on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that generates random numbers and saves them for later.

```
//fields
private readonly Random _random = new Random();
private readonly List<int> _randomNumbers = new List<int>();

public void SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _randomNumbers.Clear();

    Num1.text = GetRandom().First().ToString();
    Num2.text = GetRandom().First().ToString();
    Num3.text = GetRandom().First().ToString();
    Num4.text = GetRandom().First().ToString();
    Num5.text = GetRandom().First().ToString();
    Num6.text = GetRandom().First().ToString();
}

public void SortRandomNumbers(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sortedRandoms = _randomNumbers;
    sortedRandoms.Sort();

    //do stuff with sortedRandoms
}

// Gets a random value and caches it
private IEnumerable<int> GetRandom()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var value = _random.Next(1, 49);
        _randomNumbers.Add(value);

        yield return _randomNumbers.Last();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you always have six fields Num1 - Num6, you could add their content to a `List<int>`, sort them by using `.OrderBy()` and fill them up again using the ordered list.

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
nums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Num1.text));
.
.
nums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Num6.text));
nums = nums.OrderBy(num => num).ToList(); //or OrderByDescending
Num1.text = nums[0];
.
.
Num6.text = nums[5];
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you could use an Array:

```
RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    numbers[i] = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();

numbers.Sort();
```

Comment: What is so bad about ArrayList ?

Comment: @MikeTWebb - I think it may be because ArrayLists lack type safety and they're not as efficient as other suitable collections. Everything is stored as an `object` type in an `ArrayList` so it's generally slower than a `List<T>` as casting has to be performed. Since you don't need any of the ArrayList features that a List<T> can't perform (e.g. store multiple types of objects), it seems less efficient to use it.